# How to pass value from 2d array with prepareForSegue

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, segue

I have a array like this in a `tableView`:

```
var array: [[String]] = [["Apples", "Bananas", "Oranges"], ["Round", "Curved", "Round"]]
```

I would like to pass on the name of the cell when the cell is pressed. With a standard array I would do this:

```
 let InfoSegueIdentifier = "ToInfoSegue"

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        if segue.identifier == InfoSegueIdentifier
        {
            let destination = segue.destination as! InfoViewController
            let arrayIndex = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row
            destination.name = nameArray[arrayIndex!]
          }
    }
```

And in the next `ViewController` (`InfoViewController`)

```
var name = String()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
nameLabel.text = name
    }
```

Error: "Cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type 'String'"

Comment: What do you want stored in nameLabel.text?

Comment: 'array' which you defined is string array inside an array, so this error will definitely come.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this part of code

```
if segue.identifier == InfoSegueIdentifier
{
     let destination = segue.destination as! InfoViewController
     let arrayIndex = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row
     destination.name = nameArray[arrayIndex!]
}
```

To

```
if segue.identifier == InfoSegueIdentifier
{
   let destination = segue.destination as! InfoViewController
   let arrayIndexRow = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row
   let arrayIndexSection = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.section
   destination.name = nameArray[arrayIndexSection!][arrayIndexRow!]
 }
```

Try and share the results.

**Reason For crash**: In your first viewController you have **[[String]]** which is the datasource for your section. Now, when you try to get the object from this array it will returns you **[String]** and in your destination viewController you have the object of type **String**. and while assigning **[String] to String** it cause the crash with type mismatch. So, what above code does is, it will take first **[String]** from the **arrayIndexSection** and then the **String** from **arrayIndexRow** and thus pass a String object to destination.

Hope it clears.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are passing an array to second view controller and there is a variable of type string. So, replace this method like this.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        if segue.identifier == InfoSegueIdentifier
        {
            let destination = segue.destination as! InfoViewController
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{
                 destination.name = nameArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
            }

        }
    }
```